# Access violation error with ioStream

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, iostream, access-violation

I am creating an ioStream and then using an operator overloaded in a dll:

```
  std::istrstream wStream((char *)aString,strlen(aString));
  wStream >> wValue;
```

aString is a const char* received as a parameter.
The second line causes this runtime error:

> 0xC0000005:Access Violation reading location 0x00000020

However, when I replace the second line with the actual code of the operator overload function, I get no error.

Note that I am building this in Visual Studio 2010, and the same code runs with no error when compiled with Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: can you elaborate on this? What is aString in this example? What is wValue? You've almost certainly experienced undefined behaviour here, but helping beyond that is hard without more information.

Comment: also  [strstream is deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e4xe3f4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), precisely because of the dangers with c style strings and the c style cast can mask other problems which might be causing you trouble here too.

Comment: I did try using istrstream instead of istrstream, but I still get the same error. Also, aString is an const char *, and wValue is an object which overloads the >> operator.

Comment: What is the type of aString and how is it initialized.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without context about how `aString` is set but `istrstream` is a deprecated class. Have you considered trying `istringstream` instead as a test to help narrow things down?

```
std::istringstream wStream(std::string(aString));
wStream >> wValue;
```

EDIT: upon further consideration this looks suspiciously like your `aString` is actually null, and as the `strstream` tries to read from it, eventually it dies to an access violation. Try printing out the raw pointer value of `aString` prior to doing the string stream operations (something like `std::cout << static_cast<void*>(aString) << std::endl;`)